# Postgres gin Index for two words search

Tags: postgresql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization, database-performance

Aurora Postgres 12.8

Wildcard searches are working perfectly using gin index as under on multiple tables having millions of rows each.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name  ON table_name USING gin  (column_name gin_trgm_ops);
select col1, col2 from table_name where column_name ~* ('wild_text');
```

Life was good till the new requirement of searching for 'two-letter words' arrived.

```
select col1, col2 from table_name where column_name ~* ('aa');
```

since 'gin_trgm_ops' creates "trigram index" so 1 and 2 character search bypass index, needless to explain what happens next.

**Question:**
Is there any option to create a gin index that supports 1 and 2 character search, unlike 'gin_trgm_ops'? Or any other solution for my case?

Wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no good solution. But that is not so much a question of missing features as a matter of principle: very short search strings tend to produce large result sets, and indexes cannot help a lot with that.

My recommendation is to enforce a lower length limit of 4 or even higher on the length of the search string.